# Should I check endianness when using System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(aString)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, encoding

I'm writing something that convert data to byte[], transferring through internet, then convert back to what they were for a Unity game project.

I use `BitConverter` to convert `int`, `float`, etc., as the following example shows:

```
float aFloat = 312321f;
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(aFloat);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(bytes);

// sending through the internet
byte[] bytes = GetByteArrayFromTheInternet();
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(bytes);
float aFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
```

I do the endianness check before and after sending the data to make sure they're the same. Do I need to do this for `string`?

```
string aString = "testing";
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(aString);
// if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(bytes); // Do I need this line?

// sending through the internet
byte[] bytes = GetByteArrayFromTheInternet();
// if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(bytes); // Do I need this too?
string aString = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do the endianess check before and after sending the data to make sure they're the same. Do I need to do this for string?

That depends on who you're talking to on the network. What endianness are they using?

In your first example, you are assuming that the network protocol *always* sends `float` types (32-bit floating point) as big-endian. Which is fine; traditionally, "network host order" has always been big-endian, so it's a good choice for a network protocol.

But there's no *requirement* that a network protocol comply with that, nor that it be internally self-consistent, and you haven't provided any information about what protocol you're implementing.

Note: by "network protocol", I'm referring to the application-level protocol. This would be something like HTTP, SMTP, FTP, POP, etc. I.e. whatever your application chooses for the format of bytes on the network.

So, you'll have to consult the specification of the protocol you're using to find out what endianness the Unicode-encoded (UTF16) data uses. I would *guess* that it's big-endian, since your `float` values are too. But I can't say that for sure.

Note that if the network protocol does encode text as big-endian UTF16, then you don't need to swap the bytes for each character yourself. Just use the [`BigEndianUnicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.bigendianunicode) encoding object to encode and decode the text. It will handle the endianness for you.

Note also that it's not really optional to use the right encoder. All that checking the `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` field tells you is the current CPU architecture. But if the text on the network protocol is encoded as big-endian, then even if you are running on a big-endian CPU, you still need to use the `BigEndianUnicode` encoding. Just like that one will always reliably decode big-endian text, the `Unicode` encoding *always* decodes the text as if it's little-endian, even when running on a big-endian CPU.

Comment: Thank you, seems it's more complex than I thought. By "network protocol" do you mean something like UDP, TCP?  I'm writing for a Photon Bolt project, not sure if you heard of it. I'd better check their documentations.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. I mean, yes...UDP and TCP are protocols, but I mean the application-layer protocol. More like HTTP, POP, SMTP, FTP, etc. These are all layered on top of the lower-level network protocols you mention, and they can define whatever byte format they want. I don't know anything about the Photon Bolt stuff, but yes...checking the docs for that would be a good place to start. Though, if you're having to decode `float` values yourself, that suggests to me that that particular library leaves all the byte-ordering decisions to you. Do you control both ends?

Comment: I just googled, Photon uses little endian. Does that mean I should convert all `byte[]` to little endian if the CPU is big endian? And using `Encoding.Unicode` is fine since it's as you said little endian.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledges about internet related programming. Yes I control both ends. I just read from Mirosoft doc of `BitConverter` that they do the endianness check in an example, so I thought maybe I should do that too for `string`.

Comment: If indeed Photon only uses little-endian, then yes...you'd have to make sure you swap bytes when deserializing `float` and the like on a big-endian CPU. That said, you should double-check your search results; I couldn't find anything regarding endianness for Photon Bolt, and from your code example it doesn't seem like it's doing any serialization/deserialization for you. Or are you implementing an endpoint that _doesn't_ use Bolt, to communicate with one that does?

Comment: For what it's worth, it's _much_ more important that you focus on what the byte-order is for whatever protocol you're implementing. The only reason the question of swapping bytes come up is because you're using `BitConverter`, which is so closely tied to the machine architecture. But you could easily write your own similar class to do the same kind of byte-to-object conversions which always uses big-endian regardless of machine architecture. Alternatively, use one someone else wrote (e.g. https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229012/discussion-between-peter-duniho-and-arts).

Comment: It has a feature to do serialization/deserialization, but that feature has size limitations. So I need to write my own serialization/deserialization to stream bigger data. I'll double check the endianness. I try to conclude this in short please correct me if I'm wrong:

Comment: 1 If Photon Bole uses little-endian, then I do the check and converting before sending and after receiving the byte array for data that is not string. Check the CPU, if it's bit-endian, then reverse. And use `Encoding.Unicode` for string, with no check or reverse by myself. If Photon Bolt is big endian, then vice versa for other data, and use `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode` for string. Am I right? Thank you!